# Bundle Product Price is Not Updating On Product Page - near to add to cart button. When Selecting Options

Tags: bundled-product, magento2.2.7

I have created a bundle product with 2 options.

One option is a dropdown menu (required).

The 2nd option is a checkbox (required).

When I select my options the price in the right column is not updated.

Once added to cart the price reflected is correct.

Magento version is 2.2.7

Any ideas?

(I have overrides luma theme)

Comment: Check the error log it might be override issue - In my case layout file issue of catalog_product_view.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the error log File (exception log file) it might be override issue - In my case layout file issue of catalog_product_view.xml